# Are these two sets the same

Tags: general-topology

For any non-empty subset $A$ in Euclidean space $R^n$, define its $\delta$-neighborhood as:
$$ A_{\delta}=\{x|dist(A,x)<\delta\}$$;
My question is that if we define a set as follows:
$$B_{\delta}:=\{x|dist(A,x)\le\delta\}$$.
,then is $B_{\delta}=closure(A_\delta)$?
Your answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: suppose that $X$ is a non-empty set with the discrete topology (induced by the metric $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0$) and that $A=\{x\}$ for some $x\in X$. Then $A_1=\{x\}$, which is closed, while $B_1=X$.

Edit: the question was changed after I posted my answer. When $A$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is true that $\overline{A_{\delta}}=B_{\delta}$: clearly $B_{\delta}$ is a closed set containing $A_{\delta}$. If $x\in B_{\delta}$ with $x\not\in A_{\delta}$ then $d(x,A)=\delta$. So for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is some $y_n\in A$ with $d(x,y)<\delta+\frac{1}{n}$. We can then choose a point $z_n$ on the line segment connecting $x$ and $y_n$ so that the distance between $z_n$ and $y_n$ is $<\delta$ and the distance between $z_n$ and $x$ is $<\frac{2}{n}$.

Comment: your answer is appreciated. But if $X$ is not so special, for example, $X$ is the $R^n$, $A$ is a non-empty subset of $X$, is it still not correct?

Comment: If $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ then yes, $B_\delta=\overline{A_{\delta}}$.

Comment: Could you give me a proof? I have tried to prove this but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: It should be clear that $B_{\delta}$ is closed and contains $A_{\delta}$. If $x\in B_{\delta}$ with $x\not\in A_{\delta}$, then $d(x,A)=\delta$. So for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is some $y_n\in A$ with $d(x,y)<\delta+\frac{1}{n}$. We can then choose a point $z_n$ on the line segment connecting $x$ and $y_n$ so that the distance between $z_n$ and $y_n$ is $<\delta$ and the distance between $z_n$ and $x$ is $<2/n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have got the idea clearly.

Comment: The space in consideration is R^n and not some X.

Comment: @William Elliot: The question has been edited, as you would see if you had bothered to look at the comments.

Comment: I think the downvote is a bit much, considering that I addressed both the original question and the edited one.

Comment: I'd add the proof in the comments to the answer

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: done